# Free two dimensional array

Tags: c

Having the following piece of code:

```
 int (*fd)[2];                                                         
 int memory = n * sizeof(int);                             
 fd = malloc(memory);
```

How should I correctly free the allocated memory?

Comment: One call to `malloc()` - one call to `free()`. Just `free(fd)`.

Comment: When you allocate this way, you must be sure that `n` contains the total number of `int` elements desired, not the number of rows. It would usually be better to write `int (*fd)[2] = malloc(NumberOfRows * sizeof *fd);`. This both incorporates the number of columns into the size calculation and avoids bugs that can occur if `int` is changed in one place (the declaration of `fd`) and not another (the `sizeof` expression).

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thanks man! It was a problem. You saved my day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `free(fd)` to free the memory allocated by `malloc` to `fd`.
**NOTE:**  `free()` only marks the memory chunk as free - there is no enforcement of this freeing operation.

For detailed explanation read: [Heap Management With `malloc()` and `free()`](http://users.actcom.co.il/~choo/lupg/tutorials/unix-memory/unix-memory.html#c_alloc).